# CodedUI: Will tests still run when my computer is locked?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, remote-desktop

So I'm running CodedUI tests on a remote machine.  Everything is run on the remote machine (via Remote Desktop Connection):

1. Log into the machine via RDC
2. On the remote machine, run a batch file that executes vstest.console.exe with a bunch of arguments
3. Let it run

I know the RDC connection can't be minimized or else tests will fail.  However, what happens if I lock my main computer, i.e., the one I used to log into the remote computer?  Will the tests still run?  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some experiments I found the answer.  You can lock the machine you used to remote into the test machine, provided at least that the test machine is running the tests locally.

Comment: It's good you came up with this answer, but as @cdavid mentions if you just never RDP into your test agent you should be good. You may want to experiment with other ways to run your batch file (As part of a build process, for instance, through powershell etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Autologon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/autologon.aspx) from SysInternals. This allows you to automatically log on a user. Then, once the machine restarts and logs in the user, within that user session, you should be able to run any commands (via e.g.: PowerShell Remoting) so that your tests run.